# Android: Using custom BindingAdapters in Kotlin does not seem to work

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I've been using a simple data binder to change the visibility of views as follows:

```
public class BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("shown")
    public static void setShown(View view, boolean show) {
        view.setVisibility(show ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
    }
}
```

when I translate it to Kotlin like so:

```
object BindingAdapters {
    @BindingAdapter("shown")
    fun setShown(view: View, show: Boolean) {
        view.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
    }
}
```

I get an error that no setter for "shown" exists.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In order for the Kotlin object declaration to generate static Java methods, you'll need to annotate the method with `@JvmStatic`, like so:

```
object BindingAdapters {
  @JvmStatic
  @BindingAdapter("shown")
  fun setShown(view: View, show: Boolean) {
    view.visibility = if (show) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry but that doesn't seem to be it , I still get the same error